# App crashes when signout function is invoked from viewModel

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I have this problem but it keeps crashing when I sign out. I can't find the answer anywhere.
Context:
I have a repository with all the necessary code for firebase authentication. I have successfully implemented the login function using the await() function and it works perfectly. the thing is you cannot use await() on the firebase.signOut() function which i think is the problem. Please help.

```
 fun signIn(email: String, password: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.signInWithEmailPassword(email, password).collect { response ->
                _signInState.value = response
                Log.d("tag", response.toString())
            }
        }
    }

fun signOut() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.signOut().collect { response ->
                _signOutState.value = response
                Log.d("tag", response.toString())
            }
        }
    }
```

MAIN COMPOSABLE

```
fun HomeScreen(viewModel: HomeScreenViewModel) {
    val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    Scaffold(
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        drawerContent = { NavDrawer(onSignOutClicked = {viewModel.signOut()})}
    ) { ....... }
```

Sign-in works perfectly and it doesn't crash. the sign-out function signs out perfectly but just crashes as well.

Comment: Please attach the error log / stacktrace...

Comment: Welcome Murtaza, please open the logcat when the app crashes and paste the error message

Comment: You should post the exception stack trace so people can tell what exactly your crash cause is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FirebaseAuth#signOut()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#signOut()) method, returns void. So there is no way you call `await()` or any other methods after:

```
auth.signOut()
```

So most likely that's the reason why your app crashes.

The `await()` method is used in Kotlin for asynchronous operations. Meaning that we can suspend a coroutine until the operation finishes. But remember, the sing-out operation in Firebase is **not** asynchronous.

Comment: That is exactly what I thought. So how should I implement it without await()

Comment: There is no need to use `await()` since it's not an asynchronous operation. You have to use it like any other line of code. So simply use `auth.signOut()`. That's it.

Comment: You're very welcome, Murtaza. Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Well right now everything is clear but if I get stuck again then for sure I'll ask you. Really appreciate it.